При попытке вызвать асинхронную функцию из синхронной возникает ошибка Timeout context
При нажатии на кнопку runRobot запускается синхронная функция, которая по идее должна вызывать асинхронную с целью закрытия всех ордеров. Но при выполнении возникает ошибка:
Timeout context manager should be used inside a task, и необходимая задача в асинхронной функции не отрабатывает.
async def on_close_orders():
    global orders_info
    print('Сработала кнопка "закрыть все ордера')
    for i in orders_info:
        await client.cancel_order(symbol=i['symbol'], orderId=i['order_id'])
    orders_info = []

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.StopButton.clicked.connect(self.stopRobot)
        self.ui.CloseAllButton.clicked.connect(self.closeAll)
        self.ui.StartButton.clicked.connect(self.runRobot)
    def closeAll(self):
        global check
        if client:
            print('Закрыть все сделки')
            loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
            asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
            try:
                loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait_for(on_close_orders(), timeout=0.1))
                loop.close()
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                print("the operation timed out")
            self.ui.setBrowser.setText(f'Все сделки закрыты')

До этого использовались разные способы вызова функции, но все они либо сразу выдавали различные ошибки, либо ничего не происходило.
Подскажите, в чем ошибка вызова асинхронной функции?

Вы с предыдущим то вопросом разобрались? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1599450/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-python-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-pyside6 Там ведь тоже самое, вы разберитесь как нужно из используемого вами фреймворка запускать асинхронные задачи. А лучше вообще не смешивайте разные подходы. Кстати, добавьте в вопрос тег UI фреймворка вашего.

@CrazyElf В предыдущем вопросе была немного другая проблема - там было зависание интерфейса. Эту ошибку исправил, запустив в разные потоки интерфейс и основное выполнение программы.
Сейчас зависание отсутствует, но не получается вызвать асинхронную функцию из синхронной.

@CrazyElf, каким образом в данном кейсе можно не смешивая разные подходы написать интерфейс? Чтобы инициализировать кнопки, придется вызывать функции внутри класса как асинхронные, я так пробовал через Lambda - не получилось.

Вроде там вам что-то подсказывали в комментариях. Смешивать асинхронный подход с UI фреймворками не такая простая задача. Попробуйте как-то всё-таки разделять. У фреймворка есть свои потоки, может их использовать лучше.

@CrazyElf не ясно, что сложнее: переписать весь основной код без asyncio, или добить работу интерфейса. Сначала попробую добить интерфейс
